# Define random coordinates of a THREE.Vector3

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am extruding a spline in Three JS and I would like the z axis to be random.

For the moment I am ading a Math.random() * (10 + 10) - 10 to get a value for Z

But I have a lot of these lines and it rakes a lot of resources.

Is there a trick to make this code nicer?

Thanks!

```
var Spline6 =  new THREE.SplineCurve3( [

    new THREE.Vector3(225.8,42.3,Math.random() * (10 + 10) - 10 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(68.4,42.3,Math.random() * (10 + 10) - 10 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(62.1,42.9,Math.random() * (10 + 10) - 10 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(52.9,45.1,Math.random() * (10 + 10) - 10 ),
    new THREE.Vector3(41.9,49.8,Math.random() * (10 + 10) - 10 ),

] );


var pts = [], numPts = 32;

for ( var i = 0; i < numPts * 6; i ++ ) {

var l = 4

var a = i / numPts * Math.PI;

pts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( Math.cos( a ) * l *2, Math.sin( a ) * l ) ); 

}

var shape = new THREE.Shape( pts );

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );

var material3 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x717171, wireframe: false } );



var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material3 );

scene.add( mesh );
```